# Error while doing a POST call from Angular to Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've created a Firebase Cloud Function and it's working;

```
export const deleteUser = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  const userEmail = request.body.userEmail;
  await admin.auth().getUserByEmail(userEmail)
    .then(function (userRecord:any) {
      const uid = userRecord.uid;
      admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
        .then( () => {
          console.log('User deleted');
          response.status(200).send('User deleted');
        })
        .catch(() => {
          console.log('Error deleting user');
          response.status(500).send('Failed to delete user');
        });
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('Error fetching user');
      response.status(500).send('Failed while fetching user');
    })
})
```

I've checked with Postman and everythings is ok, it deletes the user from Firebase as expected.
[Screenshot of the call from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MYLq.png)

I call my service from my component, and works fine.

```
removeUser(userUid:any, userEmail:any){
    userEmail = {'userEmail': userEmail};
    this.authService.gdelete(userEmail).subscribe();
    // this.usersService.removeUser(userUid);
  }
```

The problem is when I call the Cloud Funtcion from my Angular Service.

```
  gdelete(userEmail:any) {
    //no consigo conectar el post con la cloud function 
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      })
    };
    return this.http.post('https://myfirebaseserver.cloudfunctions.net/deleteUser', {body: userEmail}, httpOptions);
  }
```

It displays the following error:
[Screenshot of the error in the browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJSHw.png)

I think the problem is when I call the cloud function. I've serched on SO lots of posts related and implemented the solutions but nothing worked.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help] useful when it comes to [ask], and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question. Why I shouldn't upload code as image https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Can you please expand the error in the last image and paste the code?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and feedback! I've edit the post expanding the error and formating better. Hope is fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uknown error 0 (in this cases) means CORS are not well set.
Try to add 'cors' npm package to your Function:
npm install cors

Then add these lines:

```
// Add CORS to your index.TS
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});



// Put this line to your function
// Automatically allow cross-origin requests
cors(req, res, () => {});
```

Another error that I can see, you are sending two json level in the body:
{ body: { XXX: XXX } }

on your post in client, just send 'userEmail', like this:

````
return this.http.post('https://XXXXXXX.cloudfunctions.net/deleteUser', userEmail, httpOptions);```

dont forget to replace the XXX with your server.
````